# How do i change back the innerhtml with jQuery in an click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following function:

```
$('#jaTack').click(function() {
        $('#syskon').slideToggle();
        $('#jaTack').html('Hide');
    });
```

So `#jaTack` is an id of a button, when pressed shows the content of id `#syskon`.
When the button is pressed ,I change the inner html of that button with `.html()`, from 'Show' to 'Hide'. That's all nice, but i am not sure how i should do when it's pressed once again,
so that the innerhtml of the button becomes 'Show' again?

Hope anyone have the time to help me out.

Comment: I don't think he deserves to get downvoted - this is a valid "newbie" question, and he put in way more effort than 'I can haz code plz?', so why be so hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) `?:` like this

```
$('#jaTack').click(function() {
    $('#syskon').slideToggle();
    $('#jaTack').html($('#jaTack').html() == "Show" ? "Hide" : "Show");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a very nice looking solution, which worked like a charm for me! :)

Comment: When using this solution, I'd suggest defining constants for both texts to get rid of the redundancy.

Comment: html of element and accessed once and assigned once, can you explain what is redundant?

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the state somewhere, why not an anonymous function?

```
$('#jaTack').click((function() {
    var toggle = false;
    return function () {
        if (toggle) {
            $('#jaTack').html('Show');
        } else {
            $('#jaTack').html('Hide');
        }
        $('#syskon').slideToggle();
        toggle = !toggle;       
    };
}());   // immediate invocation because we're awesome
```

Comment: +1 for nice use of returned anonymous function.  At first I was like, "Eh?" and then I was like, "Ahhhhh!"

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm sure it's helpful for someone. I thought that the answer i accepted was easier for this task. But i thank you again for your time and answer.